# Implied volatility of inverse quote

Tags: options, volatility, implied-volatility, fx

Suppose I have a quote of INR/USD and the implied vol surface is also given.
Is it theoritically correct to use to same implied vol for analysis of the inverse quote, i.e. USD/INR.

Correct me if I am wrong, but standard deviation of x and 1/x are not same.

Comment: _Correct me if I am wrong, but standard deviation of x and 1/x are not same_:  If x is lognormal, then SD(x) = SD(1/x).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implied vol at strike $1/K$ and maturity $T$ for USDINR under the **INR** $T$-forward measure is the same than the implied vol at strike $K$ and maturity $T$ for INRUSD under the **USD** $T$-forward measure.

This is a consequence of a Call on INRUSD with payoff in USD being equivalent to a Put on USDINR with payoff in INR.